# Sequence date and data frame

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am foresting with ets function from the forecast package.I have daily data from sales for each days in the period from 2015-01-01 until 2015-12-01.Output from this coding is forecast object.This forecast object don't have properly date so I must put forecast into table.

```
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

forecast_horizont<-10

DATA_TEST<-data.frame(date_of_sale = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-01"), by = "day"),
                      value=sample(1:50, 335, replace=TRUE))
```

For the purpose of forecasting, next step should be how to make table like table below.

[image]

In below code line I must put forecast_horizont and for that reason I try with this line of code.But there is problem and this line does not work.

```
EXPAND_DATA_set<-data.frame(date_of_sale = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-12-01"), by = "day")+forecast_horizont)
```

So can anybody help me how to fix this line of code and make table like table on above pic with using forecast_horizont ?

Comment: You only have 1 date in `seq.Date(as.Date("2015-12-01"), by = "day")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to add `forecast_horizont` days starting from `"2015-12-01"` ?

```
data.frame(date_of_sale = seq(as.Date("2015-12-01"), by = "day", length.out = forecast_horizont))

#   date_of_sale
#1    2015-12-01
#2    2015-12-02
#3    2015-12-03
#4    2015-12-04
#5    2015-12-05
#6    2015-12-06
#7    2015-12-07
#8    2015-12-08
#9    2015-12-09
#10   2015-12-10
```

OR

```
data.frame(date_of_sale = as.Date('2015-12-01') + 0:forecast_horizont)
```